# Slow self hosted wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

we have a great site which has been humming along nicely for about 5 months and then in May it went from a page load speed time of 3-5 secs to now an agonising 15+ secs!!!

The host has been really helpful and has even shifted the site to a new server which is faster!

I guess seeing as though we do not have the insight or your expertise we would ask the Serverfault community and see what this crowd of experts could recommend?

Appreciate any insight, thank you.

site is here: integrati.com.au

Comment: You've given us almost no information at all - what's the server? what's it's OS? versions? what have you done so far to identify the problem? come on, you have to give us something

Comment: Apologies, I am new at this here we go:

Architecture   i686
Operating system  Linux
Apache version  2.2.15
PHP version   5.2.13

Have cleaned up a lot of code with the help of a coder and now only have these two issues in Firebug:

Comment: OK Firebug suggests:

Parralellize Downloads
Server Static content from cookieless domain

Overall rating is 80/100

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

First thing to do is to start disabling plugins.  Do them one at a time, testing the site for a little while in between each disabling.

Comment: +1 It may well be some slow-running code in one of the plugins, so this is a good place to start.  It may be worth considering enabling a caching plugin to help compensate for slow-running code.

Comment: Nice suggestion but have already tried this! 

:)

Comment: @Integrati: so a bare, base-level WordPress install is slow then?  No plugins active?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to determine which external script(s) is slow in loading.

Reset your permalinks (and see what else is in .htaccess) becuase your page links are 404ing.

Comment: Sorry, how do you 'reset' permalinks? please.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: I have looked at the Permalinks Songdogtech but not sure what benefit re-setting these would have.

Can you share some insight please?

:)

Answer (score 2):

Install YSlow (http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and have a look at your site with it. Reducing the number of items to download (css, js) etc. will improve performance. Ensure they're cachable and compressed.

Check the number of clients your webserver can handle concurrently - if the site is being slow while there's still plenty of resources available you may need to increase this.

Comment: Yslow shows that lots of resources are being pulled from external sites. That'll certainly slow things down, but there's probably also something else causing the delay because much of the wait was in the initial connection to the site.

Comment: Thank you, I have been using Y-Slow and Firebug... will do some more digging into the initial connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is definitely slow, but there are things to do on your site as well.
Try this tool http://unshit.com It points out what should you change first.

Answer (score 0):

quick whois lookup revealed  ns13.wordpresshosting.com.au as your name server.

wordpresshosting.com.au site tells me that unless u're paying 99/month for dedicated server - than you re probably chuggin along on plain old SHARED hosting plan - which sucks for  anything more than a home page!

Last time I checked - my shared hosting(ixwebhosting) was hosting something like 90-100 sites on a singlecore 2.8Ghz. I mean - WOW....wow... So yeah - all websites on that server were throttled to only 1% of that PC's capacity or something like that.

also..mmm... I checked it with Yslow and most of the optimizations that you would really benefit from haven't been done. Gzipping and combining css/js files would save you site half of your loading time. Like typeface.js file is 205 Kb can be gzipped to around 50 kb - that's big. Also ... IMHo - I'm questioning the need for this file entirely. Looks like it *ucks with fonts/css using JS which is a bad idea cuz all messing around with fonts should be done through CSS itself - this is what CSS has been designed for.

Also - coders don't used boxed cms like wordpress - coders use php frameworks and code from scratch (CI, Zend etc). Designers like Wordpress cuz it's easy - but sucks for customizations/optimizations like this one.

Anyway - hope this help pal.